# Sharing Azure DevOps Portal with Azure DevOps Server 2020

Tags: azure, azure-devops-server-2019, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

We already have pipelines on Azure Devops portal that connects to repos on the cloud.
I created pipelines to trigger when files are committed on the repos and to run on self hosted agents.

We use to have some internal repos on a TFS server on-premises that we migrated to Azure DevOps Server 2020 Update 1.1.

I would like to get advices or best practices on how to reuse agents, YAMLs and scripts between the portal and on-premises.

Would you recommend use the same self hosted agents ?

Could I access the YAML and PS1 scripts that are on an Azure repo on the cloud from my on-premises Azure DevOps Server ?

Thanks,
Claude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would you recommend use the same self hosted agents?

Not recommend and cannot implement this feature.

When you configure the Self-hosted agent, you need to use Organization url/Collection URL. One single agent can only connect to one organization.

You cannot share agnets between Azure DevOps service and Azure Devops server.

I suggest that you can create agents for Azure DevOps service and Azure DevOps server separately on the same machine, so that you can ensure that they run the pipeline on the same environment.

> Could I access the YAML and PS1 scripts that are on an Azure repo on the cloud from my on-premises Azure DevOps Server ?

If you want to directly use the YAML files in the Azure DevOps Service repo to create a pipeline on the Azure DevOps server, you need to **clone the repo** to the Azure DevOps server to achieve this.

In Azure DevOps Server, If you want to create a Pipeline without cloning the repo, you can use the **Other Git** option to use the repo in Azure DevOps Service, this option only supports the Classic Mode Pipeline.

[image]